# How do I add an annotation with Django annotate on a QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model class with a **status** field, which might have several alternatives, say:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    status_choices = (
        ('status1', 'status1'),
        ('status2', 'status2'),
        ('status3', 'status3'),
        ('status4', 'status4'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(choices=status_choices)
```

Then I want to annotate the instances with an `active` field which might be either `True` or `False`. The instance is `active` when status is IN [status1, status2].

Django version is 1.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a [**`Case`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, Value, When

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    active=Case(
        When(status__in=['status1', 'status2'], then=Value(True))
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

Note that the list of the `status__in` condition should contain the *keys* of the choices (so the left item of the tuples, not the right one).